# GNUPLOT if I have 30 data/1sec the code not working,why?

Tags: gnuplot

Hy
I wonder when I working with same code, but the data is only 1 data / 1 second - the code is working,
But when I change the sensor sample rate to about 30 Hz , so 30 data / 1 second I get this plot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6A2j.jpg]

I want to something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5USB6.jpg]

the code what i use is this:

```
set term png
set autoscale yfix
set autoscale xfix 
set grid
#set offsets 0,0,30,30
#set offsets 0,0,30,30
set offsets graph 0, 0, 50, 50

PATCH = system("cat ./outputs/lastPatch.txt")

set title "MPU-9150 IMU sensor: RAW Accelerometer "
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set format x '%H:%M:%S'
set xtics rotate
set xlabel "[time]"
set ylabel "[-]"
#set output "./outputs/IMUrawAccel.png"
set output sprintf("%sIMUrawAccel.png",PATCH)
#plot './outputs/IMUrawAccel.txt' using 1:2 title 'X' with lines, './outputs/IMUrawAccel.txt' using 1:3 title 'Y' with lines  , './outputs/IMUrawAccel.txt' using 1:4 title 'Z' with lines   
plot sprintf("%sIMUrawAccel.txt",PATCH) using 1:2 title 'X' with lines, sprintf("%sIMUrawAccel.txt",PATCH) using 1:3 title 'Y' with lines  , sprintf("%sIMUrawAccel.txt",PATCH) using 1:4 title 'Z' with lines
```

And the output of the sensor is this (what I use in gnuplot)

```
22:20:59         2704       -1310      -15666   
22:20:59         2886       -1278      -15716   
22:20:59         2860       -1322      -15734   
22:20:59         2844       -1322      -15684   
22:20:59         2854       -1362      -15680   
22:20:59         2834       -1242      -15766   
22:20:59         2864       -1320      -15830   
22:20:59         2836       -1304      -15724   
22:20:59         2882       -1342      -15744   
22:20:59         2888       -1266      -15794   
22:20:59         2940       -1336      -15774   
22:20:59         2866       -1282      -15786   
22:20:59         2860       -1320      -15756   
22:20:59         2810       -1340      -15710
```

Comment: Well, your timestamps in the source data only have 1-second resolution so the results cannot be sensible with 30 points for every entry. You will need to generate log data in higher resolution, or if the points are distributed uniformly in time then you might extrapolate the time axis based on the row number instead of using explicit timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple datapoints with the same timestamps.

So if you plot them by timestamp, they will end up on the same x-coordinate.

There are several possible solutions.

1. Change the sensor output to include e.g. milliseconds. This is by far the preferred solution.
2. If there are a constant number of points with the same timestamp (say 30), you could use the `every` keyword: `plot sprintf("%sIMUrawAccel.txt",PATCH) every 30 using 1:2 title 'X' with lines`
3. If that is not possible, write a script to enhance the timestamp. Count the number of data-points with the same time-stamp, and then add some milliseconds to each timestamp to space them evenly. (Assuming of course that the data *is* evenly spaced.)
4. Just plot the points *without the time*: `plot sprintf("%sIMUrawAccel.txt",PATCH) using :2 title 'X' with lines`

Comment: It is possible, to plot only for example the 30th´s data ? if yes, then how? (the time is not from the sensor, but from the RTC (real time clock)  module )